# How do I execute a lot of SQL queries without problems?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL file with 30,000 UPDATE lines. When I upload it through phpmyadmin it freezes at a certain point and doesn't update everything.

Is there a way to execute all 30,000 lines, without problems, all at once? or do I have to go through and manually execute 200 lines at a time?

**Line Example:**

```
UPDATE `table` SET `value1`='Some text', `value2`=0 `value3`=1 WHERE id=500;
```

^ I have 30,000 lines like that.

Comment: I suspect this depends on whether the "freezing" is due to some SQL error and/or bug and/or configuration... any error message(s) ? what do the logs show ?

Comment: yeah, it's better to do updates in small batches.

Comment: Can you show us some of these lines? What I am trying to get to is this: is there any way that either the WHERE clauses or the values can be computed?

Comment: 30000 updates indicates something wrong. I guess that they can be written in few queryes. There shoul be a pattern. Can you post more lines?

Comment: This might be because of [max_execution_time (PHP)](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHPMyAdmin's query parsing is slow. It's much better to log into server via SSH and execute the command using mysql client:

```
$ mysql -uUsername -pPassword DatabaseName < script.sql
```

If you don't have SSH access, you can upload the sql script (via FTP, for example) and write a small PHP script that calls the command using [system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php), [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or similar PHP function:

```
<?php
system('mysql -uUsername -pPassword DatabaseName < script.sql');
```

Then invoke the script via browser.

Make sure you use full paths to mysql (/usr/bin/mysql usually) and your script file.

If you use non-system character set, make sure you [add the default_character_set](http://www.backwardcompatible.net/post/8783412531/weird-characters-in-restored-mysql-database) option as well.